# Removing the BIOS passwords on a Fujitsu LifeBook T4210?

Tags: bios, passwords

Buying laptops on police and government auctions is a real pain when they don't remove passwords.

On boot, over the Fujitsu logo, I get a Windows XP 'basic' theme style password window. Entering three wrong passwords results in a continuous beep that can only be stopped by removing the battery.

It did have a problem with the fan, and while it had that it would stop to complain about it and I could try to get to BIOS setup, where it would ask for a password with the typical text-gui type box. Can't seem to get to that now.

It would also give me the option to continue, where it would pop up the HDD password box. In either of those, three wrong tries and it would beep.

I never get any sort of 'secret code'.

This is a Fujitsu laptop, not a Fujitsu-Siemens.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this and it worked.

Remove BIOS password from a Fujitsu or Fujitsu-Seimens laptop.

- On boot screen Press F2. You must be in Bios Setup Screen which is (Phoenix SecureCore(tm) Setup Utility)
- To get to BIOS setup you may have to force a keyboard error by holding F2 plus some other keys while turning the laptop on.
- Attempt to login using these passwords, one after the other:

  1. 3hqgo3
  2. jqw534
  3. 0qww294e

Do not enter passwords again until you get a master password

- Enter the displayed code, without hyphens, at bios-pw.org
- For a Fujitsu LifeBook T4210 the good result was the 2nd one.
- On the Master Password Input Box use the decrypted code if you use the online site use the Fujitsu-Siemens
- Use the Decrypted hash code as your current password To Clear the Supervisor Password

Source: [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1du5vQO58Y)

Comment: It looks like this is copied from somewhere, can you please [cite your sources](https://superuser.com/help/referencing)?

Answer (score 0):

Ouch ... `BIOS` Password can be resetted of course. You "just" have to reinstall your BIOS and it's not sure if it will help.

Please don't set `BIOS` Password until you really need it... and the only case that comes to my mind where this is needed is when strangers use the Computer and can reboot them (they shouldn't be allowed to this)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1du5vQO58Y